# How to resolve ERROR 1044(42000): Access denied for user. In mysql (command prompt)

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql command prompt after opening command prompt I hit command **create database student** but I got one error :(

> mysql> create database student;
>   ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'student'
>   mysql>

how to correct it ?

Comment: When you get access denied, it's a good idea to make sure you're authenticated with a user with the necessary rights to do the operation.

Comment: but how do I get authentication? When I am using browser that's working properly but in command prompt where do I get authentication?